# Room not finding setter method for an entity

Tags: java, android, android-room

Room is not finding setType method defined in the parent class. Gives cannot find setter for field error during compilation.

Parent class

```java
public class Data {
    private int type = -1;
    public Data() {

    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Data setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Child class

```
@Entity
public class Log extends Data {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    public Log() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `setType(int)` is certainly available on `Log`, so what exactly is your problem? Can you update your question to include any error messages.

Comment: Room does not find setType(int) method. Error cannot find setter for field

Comment: I can only imagine that `Room` is expecting the setter to be `void setType(int)` and cannot find it because you are returning a `Data`. For example, it may be using reflection. Change `setType(int)` to return `void` and create a different method for your builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Usually setters do not return values.

Change your `setType()` method to:

```
public void setType(int type) {
      this.type = type;
}
```

P.S. Obviously, returning the same instance of `Data` object is useless here, since you're invoking the method on that object and already have it.

Comment: I'm using builder pattern

Comment: @KodakGifted, obviously, you have a conflict then. Leave the setter in the form Room expects it to be. And rename your builder's `setType()` method. This is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: The designers of Room obviously did not think this through

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the builder pattern, you could consider using an internal static class for that matter as follows (you don't need an empty constructor, that's added implicitly):

```
public class Data {
    private int type = -1;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Data data = new Data();

        public Builder setType(int type) {
            data.setType(type);
            return this;
        }

        public Data build() {
            return data;
        }
    }     
}
```

Now, for creating a data class you could do:

```
Data data = new Data.Builder()
        .setType(10)
        .build();
```